# Print a js variable inside the function

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

I want to get the value onclick and print it in symbol `"symbol": +sym+`,
.
check my code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.4.min.js"></script>

</head>
<body>
<p>click here</p>

  <!-- TradingView Widget BEGIN -->
  <script type="text/javascript" src="https://d33t3vvu2t2yu5.cloudfront.net/tv.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){    
      $("p").click(function(){
          var sym = $(this).val();
          alert("alert is working but value is not updating in symbol input");
      });
  });

  new TradingView.widget({
    "width": 400,
    "height": 450,
    "symbol": +sym+,
    "interval": "D",
    "timezone": "Etc/UTC",
    "theme": "White",
    "style": "1",
    "locale": "en",
    "toolbar_bg": "#f1f3f6",
    "allow_symbol_change": true,
    "hideideas": true,
    "show_popup_button": true,
    "popup_width": "1000",
    "popup_height": "650",
    "no_referral_id": true
  });
  </script>
  <!-- TradingView Widget END -->


</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Because a p tag doesn't have a value?

Comment: Learn how to post a question

Comment: Oh and by the way, your variable "sym" is in a different scope, you cannot access it in your widget.

Comment: @Warrior sir that is my question that how can i access a variable inside the widget.

Comment: @Amit sorry sir i am new here. I will try my best to learn that's why i came here.

Comment: I told you they're in different scopes. Move your widget inside jQuery ready function. On every click a new widget gets created. Is that what you want?

Comment: You can bind a one-shot click handler and create your widget in there. Checkout https://api.jquery.com/one/

Comment: yes sir these symbols changes the widgets according to their code written in symbol parameter.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all you need to change this   **`"symbol": +sym+`**,  to this:   **`"symbol": sym,`**. If what you want to achieve is to change the value of the variable "sym" inside the new "TreadingView.widget" object everytime you click on the paragraph "p" you are doing it wrong. You need to update that value everytime the element is clicked, otherwise the widget object will always hold the original value of the variable "sym", you need to 1)Update the "sym" value and then 2)Recreate the widget or update, you may use:

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.4.min.js"></script>

</head>
<body>
<p>click here</p>

  <!-- TradingView Widget BEGIN -->
  <script type="text/javascript" src="https://d33t3vvu2t2yu5.cloudfront.net/tv.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){    
      $("p").click(function(){
          var sym = $(this).text();
          new TradingView.widget({
              "width": 400,
              "height": 450,
              "symbol": sym,
              "interval": "D",
              "timezone": "Etc/UTC",
              "theme": "White",
              "style": "1",
              "locale": "en",
              "toolbar_bg": "#f1f3f6",
              "allow_symbol_change": true,
              "hideideas": true,
              "show_popup_button": true,
              "popup_width": "1000",
              "popup_height": "650",
              "no_referral_id": true
           });
          alert("alert is working but value is not updating in symbol input");
      });
  });

  </script>
  <!-- TradingView Widget END -->


</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to change from this:

```
var sym = $(this).val();
```

to  this:

```
var sym = $(this).html();
```

or to this:

```
var sym = $(this).text();
```

depending on what you want to get. You may know that the `p` tag doesn't hold a `value` property.

Comment: actually problem is here ("symbol": +sym+) i want to print the value here and i don't know how to print a variable here.

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
       <script type="text/javascript">
               var sym = null;
               $(document).ready(function(){    
                 $("p").click(function(){
              sym = $(this).text();
              alert("alert is working but value is not updating in symbol input");
          });
         });
         setTimeout(function(){
   sym = $(this).text();
new TradingView.widget({
          "width": 400,
         "height": 450,
         "symbol": +sym+,
         "interval": "D",
        "timezone": "Etc/UTC",
        "theme": "White",
         "style": "1",
          "locale": "en",
        "toolbar_bg": "#f1f3f6",
        "allow_symbol_change": true,
        "hideideas": true,
        "show_popup_button": true,
        "popup_width": "1000",
        "popup_height": "650",
        "no_referral_id": true
        });},5000);

         </script>
```

Comment: Not working. actually problem is here ("symbol": +sym+) i want to print the value here and i don't know how to print a variable here.

Comment: where do you want to print your sym var value ? in widget parameter or in alert ?

Comment: What if the user doesn't click in that 5 seconds timespan?

Comment: sir how can we change the value of symbol? kindly guide more.